# Double ForeignKey Relation between Models Django

Tags: python, django, sqlite, design-patterns, django-models

I'm a little confuse here:

```
class MyBirthday(Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    invitations_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location)

class Attendant(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    birthday_id = models.ForeignKey(MyBirthday)
```

The thing is whether or whether not to use the user attribute in MyBirthday model, I mean, is it okay if I just left the Attendant attribute 'birthday_id' reference it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe there will be a single birthday for one person (`MyBirthday.user`), which would have a number of attendees. In your case, you have defined a separate table for attendees.

How about you create a many-to-many field in `MyBirthday`, where you can have your attendees listed right under it?

Eg:

```py
class MyBirthday(Model):
    date = models.DateTimeField()
    invitations_quantity = models.IntegerField()
    message = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    location = models.OneToOneField(Location)
    attendees = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

Under the hood, Django will create a separate table where your attendees are stored, and you will have a cleaner model structure.

See Django documentation where more examples are shown with usage: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/